# Why is there a space between the <body> and the <html> element

Tags: html, css

Why is there a space between the top of the green box and the browser window (in Chrome and Firefox)?

There is an apparent space between the html and body element that I cannot seem to eliminate with the CSS below (and dozens of variations upon it.) there also seems to be some bonus padding on the overall document height, as if some aspect of padding or margin is not being reset to 0.

**Helpful tip**: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

I solved this problem by using the following code:

```css
div#aiport > *:first-child { margin-top: 0px }
```

while adding

```css
overflow: hidden;
```

to the `div#airport` definition by itself solved the problem *correctly.* :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>bug</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="bookmarkIcon.png" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-size: 16px;
                background: #fff;
            }
            div#airport {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 900px;
                min-width: 900px;
                max-width: 900px;
                background-color: #0f0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body lang="en">
        <div id="airport">
            <p>Platform</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser do you see the space in? Also, you shouldn't need any styles for "html", and you may need to add media="screen" to your style tag.

Comment: not in the fiddle, but I certainly do when this is loaded as a raw document in either Chrome or Firefox...

Comment: styling the html is a trick related to getting CSS gradients to work correctly... and even with that removed, there is still a space. I was trying to leave as much of the situational CSS intact in case someone knew of a specific conflict/situation that would cause a problem. This isn't a question about optimization, though I appreciate the note. :-)

Comment: You don't see it in the fiddle, because it has "Normalized CSS" checked, which removes the default margins from the `<p>` elements.

Comment: also keep in mind you should not just upvote every anser that seems to be helpful. i think you mean the gap between the GREEN DIV and the top edge of the browser display area. so some of there ansers are respondig to the "gap" between the text and the inner side of the div.

Comment: Just upvoted this question - the follow-up is "why do browsers do this?" Commonsense says the parent will expand to include the full box (including margins) of the children. Why doesn't it?

Comment: @AaronFowler Because the child margin collapses with the parent margin, instead of being a part of the content box of the parent. See zt's second comment to my answer, it references a good explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because your `<p>Platform</p>` element has a margin that pokes out of its parent `<div id="airport">` element and offsets it from the `<body>`.

Comment: ... and the source of the problem was a misunderstanding of spec: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 3):

Because `p` tag inside `#airport` has top margin on it.

If you remove the browser default top margin on that `p` tag you will no longer get the space. For example:

```
<div id="airport">
    <p style="margin:0;">Platform</p>
</div>
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNwV8/1/)

Answer (score 2):

An offset is occurring.
If you change the #airport to 
top: -20px; it will line up correct and voila, it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

make div position:absolute  you can center it again using margin-left: -(half amount of div.width px )

Comment: also keep in mind that if you are defining "margin" you dont have to define margin-top / -bottom / -left / -right as well. dont define a fixed height and a width and also a MIN and MAX  h / w .

on relative positioned divs, top:0px / bottom:0px / left:0px; right:0px doesnt make any sence. try to ceep your code as clean as possible to prevent issues further on.

Answer (score 1):

I change your CSS:

```
body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-size: 16px;
                background: #fff;
            }
            div#airport {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 900px;
                min-width: 900px;
                max-width: 900px;
                background-color: #0f0;
            }​
```

Look your code here http://jsfiddle.net/xfhyq/

Answer (score 1):

Becuase the P tag is the first Tag with text in the document, this is a common CSS problem.  try adding `body > div:first-child > p:first-child { margin-top: 0; }` to your CSS and it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default margin in body

add this to css:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: this does not correct the issue stated by the OP as the p element's top margin forces a gap nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Setting a some padding on the parent div might also solve it.

```
    div#airport {
    ...
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*As answered by lanzz:*
Its because of the `<p>Platform</p>` element which has a by default margin that pokes out of its parent `<div id="airport">` element and offsets it from the `<body>.`

To overcome this, you may add margin auto in your styles, which will help preventing such behaviour.

```
#airport p {
  margin: auto
}
```